# ¿Como clonar fila sin el checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html

para clonar una fila o mas de una dependiendo de los `checkbox` funciona bien pero al realizar por segunda ves clona 2 veces la misma fila o filas y asi si son tres veces entonces tres veces mas la misma fila o filas
La pregunta es ¿Como podría sacar el `checkbox` de la fila?

```js
$(document).ready(documentoListo)
    function documentoListo() {
     $("#cartola").click(cartola)
    }
    function cartola(){
     var result = [];
       var pos = 0;
       
     $("input[name='prestaciones[]']:checked").each(function(){
      var f=null;
      f=$(this).closest('tr').clone(false)
      $(f).appendTo(".clon");
       });
       
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tablaHisto" class="table table-striped"><thead><tr style="height: 60px;"><th style="width: 50%;text-align: center; background: #ccc">PRESTACIONES</th><th style="width: 50%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fltro" placeholder="Escriba para filtrar"></th></tr><tr><th class="d"><input class="selTodo" name="selTodo" type="checkbox">Todo</th><th class="d">Rut socio</th><th class="d">Nombre socio</th><th class="d">Nombre carga</th><th class="d">Cargo</th><th class="d">Prestacion</th><th class="d">Fecha solicitud</th><th class="d">Monto solicitado</th></tr></thead><tbody id="overno"><tr><td class="d"><input class="prestaciones" name="prestaciones[]" type="checkbox" value="183"></td><td class="d">19.367.763-0</td><td class="d">Gallardo Perez Katerinde Del Transi</td><td class="d"></td><td class="d">Monitor De Calidad</td><td class="d">Prestamos</td><td class="d">24 / 08 / 2017</td><td class="d">100.000</td></tr><tr><td class="d"><input class="prestaciones" name="prestaciones[]" type="checkbox" value="189"></td><td class="d">15.355.239-8</td><td class="d">Duarte Briones Claudia Andrea Del C</td><td class="d"></td><td class="d">Asistente Recursos Humanos</td><td class="d">Prestamos</td><td class="d">04 / 09 / 2017</td><td class="d">50.000</td></tr></tbody></table>
<button type='button' id="cartola" class='btn btn-success' value=''>Clonar</button>
<div class="tablaExcel">
   <table id="tablaHisto" class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
   <tr style="height: 60px;">
   <th style="width: 50%;text-align: center; background: #ccc">PRESTACIONES</th>
   <th style="width: 50%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fltro" placeholder="Escriba para filtrar"></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <th class="d"></th>
   <th class="d">Rut socio</th><th class="d">Nombre socio</th><th class="d">Nombre carga</th>
   <th class="d">Cargo</th><th class="d">Prestacion</th>
   <th class="d">Fecha solicitud</th>
   <th class="d">Monto solicitado</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="clon">
   
   </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La única forma que tengo de reproducir el comportamiento es dejando activado el checkbox en la fila que se ha clonado, así que la respuesta obvia es "desactivando el checkbox". ¿Hay algo que me esté perdiendo?

Comment: @SJuan76 Tienes toda la razón es eso, y como quitar el checbox o desabilitarlo al clonarlo?

Comment: tienes que buscarlo en el tr $(f).closest('[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

Comment: @DanielVorph No funciona

Comment: en que parte del código lo estas poniendo?

Comment: @DanielVorph Lo he puesto antes de `$(f).appendTo(".clon");`, despues incluso fuera del `each`